# Nuget installs old version of package Newtonsoft.Json because of WebAPI dependency

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, nuget

I have a website and dll project.

In dll packages.config I used package:
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="**6.0.3**" targetFramework="net451" />

In web site packages.config I use package:
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />. This package has dependency "Newtonsoft.Json with version >= **4.5.11**"
I added also line:
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.3" targetFramework="net451" />

when I launch "Update-Package -ReInstall" nuget checks that Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi depends on Newtonsoft.Json, then nuget **overwrites** web site packages.config with line
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="**4.5.11**" targetFramework="net451" /> and copies Newtonsoft.Json **4.5.11** into "bin" folder of site.

Also bin folder has my dll that depends on fresh version of newtonjson and it does not work..

I tried command "Update-Package -Reinstall -IgnoreDependencies". It helped partially: now I have 6.0.3 in website/bin. But there are 2 issues: should all developers on project use only "Update-Package -Reinstall -IgnoreDependencies"? They cannot launch update of nuget from GUI?
Project that not start, some dll references Newtonsoft.Json **4.5.0** (I have no exact error message because of using dependency injection).

Does anyone know:
* how to normally tell to nuget to download newtonsoft 6.0.3 to work it normally in gui?  Is there any option in packages.config for this?
* if I use newtonsoft json 6.0.3, should i use bindingRedirect to fix version on assembly for webapi?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the reason of issue

After editing packages.config for dll project and Update-Package -Reinstall command for dll project, nuget downloaded right version of Newtonsoft.Json (6.0.3) for dll project, but did not refresh path in references of project. Thus solution - **do not edit packages.config manually**. Only launch nuget commands from package manager console or gui.

Yes, **bindingRedirect** helped for the second problem